# Angular data binding inside directive template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to get simple data binding to work inside a directive template in an Angular setup.

I currently have:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
return {
    replace: true,
    restrict: 'E',  
    templateUrl: "/app/partials/template.html"
}
});
```

Inside my template.html, I have a simple input field, like so:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="name" /> 
My name is {{name}}
```

However, it displays '`{{name}}`' rather than the value typed into the input field.

If I copy this input field above outside the directive, it works.

Am I missing something when it comes to data binding within directive templates?

EDIT:

OK.  One thing i missed out here as i didn't think it was relevant was this within my directive:

```
compile:function(){
        return function link(scope,element){
            // Call a function
            steps();
         }
    }
```

The reason for this was i needed to fire a Jquery function that controls elements within the template.html.

Removing this resolves the issue, but no javascript within my template works.

Is there an easy way of calling functions within a directive template on compile?

Comment: not sure exact your looking for, can you describe what u need to achieve with relevant codes?

Answer (score 1):

probably you will get a error saying `Error: [$compile:tplrt] Template for directive 'myDirective' must have exactly one root element. ......`.

you have two options to solve this.

1. remove the `replace: true` from the directive definition
2. add a root element for the template as @Andrea Ghidini's answer

here is the [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/2KozcNTv2fsRFYpgEcck?p=preview)

Comment: Hmmm - Your example works on Plunker so there must be something else interfering with the code.  I have no JS errors or Angular errors at all.  The template.html was wrapped within a root element and was rendering correctly, it's just i am still seeing {{name}}.

Comment: umm can you create a plunker of your case, then it will be easy :)

Answer (score 0):

If you see `{{name}}` it's because you have an error in the JS, look for the error message in the browser developer tools.

In your case the problem is the template: it must contain a single html element ([link to docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/tplrt)), so you have to put something like:

```
<div>
  <input type="text" ng-model="name" /> 
  My name is {{name}}
</div>
```

Comment: That's the thing - i have no errors in the developer console and all other javascript works fine - even in the template.html.  The template.html also is wrapped within a single element.  To confirm, the template renders fine.